# MongoDB C# concatenate update objects

Tags: c#, mongodb

If you have two independent update objects:

```
var U1 = Builders<T>.Update.Set(_ => _.A, null);
var U2 = Builders<T>.Update.Set(_ => _.B, null);
```

How can you chain them so that the result would be:

```
var U = Builders<T>.Update.Set(_ => _.A, null).Set(_ => _.B, null);
```

I tried to do this:

```
var U = U1 & U2;
```

and, while it works for filters, it doesn't work for updates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add to an existing update definition by appending a new set.

```
var U1 = Builders<T>.Update.Set(_ => _.A, null);
var U = U1.Set(_ => _.B, null);
```

I admit that it is a bit funny that the `&` operator cannot be used for the Update definitions. Also: your own code hints at this as well.

In one of our projects we use this in a loop to construct a combined set  of set-operations.

Comment: `$addToSet` does not add another Set() in a fluent manner, which is what the OP is trying to do. Instead it [adds an element to an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/).

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this if you have multiple conditions or you want to use a foreach loop

```
var update = Builders<User>.Update.Combine();
if(Name != null)
{
   update = update.Set(Name, newValue);
}
```

This way you don't have to necessarily initialize the update object with a set statement.